# Trimming String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, trim

I have string like  `var a=""abcd""efgh""`.How do I print the output as `abcd""efgh` by removing first and last double quote of a string I used `a.replace(/["]/g,'')` but it is removing all the double quotes of a string.How do i get the output as `abcd""efgh`.Suggest me an idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
var a='"abcd""efgh"';
a.replace(/^"+|"+$/g, '');
```

From the comments here is the explanation

**Explanation**

- There are 2 parts `^"+` and `"+$` separated by `|` which is the regex equivalent of the or
- `^` is for starts-with and `"+` is for one or more `"`
- Similarly `$` is for ends-with
- The `//g` is for global replacement otherwise the only the first occurrence will be replaced

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP if you explained how/why this expression works.

Comment: @shyam please can you explain the expression I am beginner to javascript.Thank you It worked but it will be greatful if you can provide the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try use this

```
var a='"abcd""efgh"';
a.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
```